# DbSpatialServices.Default.Within method for DbGeography

Tags: entity-framework, spatial-query

In EF 6 I can use DbSpatialServices.Default.Within but with DbGeometry types only as parameters, how can I use the Within function with DbGeography type?

SQL Server 2012 has a new spatial function STWithin which accepts DbGeography and DbGeometry.

[Namespace:  System.Data.Entity.Spatial
Assembly:  EntityFramework (in EntityFramework.dll)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.spatial.dbspatialservices.within%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct route, but there are simple yet clever workarounds.

Use the following:

```
DbGeography geog = blah;
<your stored data>.Where(x => x.<Your Geography Column>.Intersects(geog) && x.<Your Geography Column>.Difference(geog).IsEmpty == true)
```

The call to `Intersects` ensures use of any valid SpatialIndex whilst the final `Difference` clause removes any objects that are not totally within the given DbGeography instance.

Of course, if you're just looking for Points within a Polygon, it would be wise to exclude the `Difference` clause for performance.